# How to hide the bar at the top of "youtube" even when mouse hovers over it?

Tags: youtube, embed

I am attempting to embed a youtube video, however, I have not discovered a way to keep the bar at the top from showing when the mouse hovers over it. For my purposes it is important that users are not able to have a direct link back to the original video where they can re-watch the video. The following link gives commands for embed features within youtube:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Overview

I have used the controls and disablekb features to limit viewers ability to skip and replay the video, what I need now is to disable the bar which appears at the top of the video.

(Where I have gotten http://www.youtube.com/embed/bFEoMO0pc7k?controls=0&disablekb=1&egm=1)

Comment: Is "disablekb" a typo, or some feature?

Comment: `disablekb` is a feature which disables keyboard

Answer (score 122):

**This answer no longer works as YouTube has deprecated the `showinfo` parameter.**

You can hide the embedded player's title bar by adding `&showinfo=0`. You cannot completely remove all the links to the original video. Here is the best you can do

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoid?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This code will remove the title bar, YouTube branding in controls, controls (optional, `delete controls=0` if you need controls). But a white YouTube logo will be displayed on the video with the video link.

**Update 1:** Here is a new tool that I built to generate customized youtube embed player code- [Advanced Youtube Embed Code Generator](http://codegena.com/generator/Youtube-Embed-Code-Generator.html)

Comment: No use, a youtube logo and link appears on the control bar now.

Comment: showinfo has been deprecated and is now ignored as of Sept 2018. This will no longer work unfortunately.

Answer (score 49):

Since YouTube has deprecated the showinfo parameter you can trick the player. Youtube will always try to center its video but logo, title, watch later button etc.. will always stay at the left and right side respectively.

So what you can do is put your Youtube iframe inside some div:

```
<div class="frame-container">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Then you can increase the size of frame-container to be out of browser window, while aligning it so that the iframe video comes to the center. Example:

```
.frame-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 300%; /* enlarge beyond browser width */
    left: -100%; /* center */
}

.frame-container iframe {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

Finnaly put everything inside a wrapper div to prevent page stretching due to 300% width:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="frame-container">
      <iframe></iframe>
   </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand how this answer is not accepted in 2021 :) Upvote for letting me know that YT keeps logos & Co to the left and to the right :)

Comment: Wasted my whole day to find a solution only to realize this is exactly what I had to do. You are the boss!

Comment: but bottom bar also get hidden

Comment: You are amazing! It works well

Comment: The only solution in 2022. Get this accepted pls.

Comment: worked great except there is still a gradient that appears at the top of the video when mouse is hovered

Comment: The gradient can be fixed with pointer-events:none on the iframe

Comment: it works, only problem is video image before playing is zoomed way too much. but other than that it works. except it also hides bottom controls (time navigator is working though)

Answer (score 23):

**Still working in 2023: :)**

Responsive embed with no info/controls including hiding the avatar and title on start/pause working 2021. Similar to a previous answer but making use of aspect-ratio instead of a padding hack and with a working demo.

If you need controls, you can make your own using [the JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). No matter how you embed a YouTube video though, it will always be possible to find it in the source one way or another.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/adamgreenough/pen/bGrgoNb?editors=1100)

```
<div class="youtube-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WhY7uyc56ms?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&color=white&controls=0&modestbranding=1&playsinline=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playlist=WhY7uyc56ms" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

.youtube-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    /* Keep it the right aspect-ratio */
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    /* No clicking/hover effects */
    pointer-events: none;
} 

.youtube-container iframe {
    /* Extend it beyond the viewport... */
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    /* ...and bring it back again */
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

Comment: This is very clever I like it.

Comment: Even with this trick the title of the video is still visible at the top in the beginning and on every loop.

Comment: @Dylan Doesn't seem to happen in the CodePen demo attached unless your title is reeeeeally long? In which case you could make the width and negative margin bigger to compensate.

Comment: It is working for me after tweaking the css according to my layout. in my case the container width needed to be 50vw instead of 100%

Answer (score 9):

What I did to disable the hover state of the iframe, was to use `pointer-events:none` in a css style. It shows the info on load, but after that hover shouldn't trigger showing the info.

Comment: this works in 2020 (aslong as you give playerVars correctly as well + autoplay) - the overlay shows briefly then disappears.

Comment: Good, but then you don't have controls anymore

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

`?rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;showinfo=0`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this it has worked for me.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PEwac2WZ7rU?rel=0?version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&&showinfo=0&loop=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Responsive embed using **Bootstap**

Allow browsers to determine video or slideshow dimensions based on the width of their containing block by creating an intrinsic ratio that will properly scale on any device.

**Style youtube video:**

- Select a youtube video, click on Share and then Embed.
- Select the embed code and copy it.
- Start modifying after the verison=3 
  www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?rel=0?version=3
- Be sure to add a '&' between each item.
- For autoplay: add "autoplay=1"
- For loop: add "loop=1"
- Hide the controls: add "controls=0"

For more information please visit this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay

Thanks
BanyanTheme

Comment: 1) I'm unable to reach the link. 2) This one is the only one that worked. Could you explain why the version=3 is necessary to have this work? Previous answers seem to not use it, but they did not work for me.

Comment: I see link is working and version=3 is not necessary. Why you use version?    Ans:                                       
"The Selecting content to play section has been updated to explain how to find YouTube video IDs and playlist IDs using the YouTube Data API (v3) rather than the older API version."

Answer (score 5):

To remove you tube **`controls`** and **`title`** you can do something like this.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zP0Wnb9RI9Q?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

[check this example how it look](https://jsfiddle.net/umanguSp/pt5gcv2r/)

`showinfo=0` is used to remove **title** and `&controls=0` is used for remove **controls** like **volume**,**play**,**pause**,**expend**.

Comment: @Flimm `showinfo=0` was removed in 2018, about a year after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers the `showinfo=0` query parameter no longer works. YouTube always provides access to the video URL when using the iframe embed method.

One way to work around this is to cover the player entirely with a separate player. [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) for example does this.

In the case of WordPress there are dedicated plugins for preventing access to the video, such as [Protected Video](https://wordpress.org/plugins/protected-video/).

Answer (score 0):

Answer in present situation is that youtube change policy since `August 23, 2018` and effective since `September 25, 2018` so they are now allow to hide info.

Answer (score -3):

Open youtube video. Click on share option. In share option click on embed tag.
You can see in embed tag there is some check box. Unchecked on show video title and player actions. After this just copy frame tag.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uqhnxAjK7qY?autoplay=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: it's not working as things have changed since 25th september 2018